# PayPal for Play2 / Scala

Tags: scala, paypal, paypal-ipn, lift

I am looking for a decent implementation of Paypal's IPN for reuse in a play application.

I found https://github.com/liftmodules/paypal but have no idea if this can easily be reused or ported or if better implementations exist for play-framework. I havent found any other that look either stable / maintained or so simple that I can understand them myself...

Here's my technical question:
(how) Can I "use" (that) lift-modules inside play-framework ?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the usage `PayPal API` like in this [example](https://github.com/aseigneurin/paypal-sample/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/seigneurin/PaypalPaymentExample.scala) or directly use PayPal's [core sdk](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.paypal.sdk/paypal-core/1.7.0). You must specify next parameters (some of them are optional, for more details see PayPal's [specificaion](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/)):

- clientID
- clientSecret
- tokenCredential
- accessToken
- amountDetails
- transaction
- redirectUrl

Comment: Looks good, thanks! a pity that I have to fall back to Java (again). I did so for using sendgrid on heroku as well. All these services should provide proper Scala wrappers for the clients.